# Prove $f$ is differentiable at $M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Denote: $f:M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(X)=X^3$.

> Prove $f$ is differentiable at $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and find $(Df(A))(X) \quad \forall A,X \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

My solution:

Denote $A,H \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.
\begin{align}
f(A+H) - f(A) 
&= (A+H)^3 - A^3 \\ 
&= A^3+AHA+HA^2+H^2A+A^2H+AH^2+HAH+H^3-A^3 \\
&= AHA+HA^2+H^2A+A^2H+AH^2+HAH+H^3.
\end{align}
Therefore, $(DF(A))(H) = AHA+HA^2+H^2A+A^2H+AH^2+HAH$.
Now,
\begin{align}
\lim_{|H| \to 0} \frac{f(A+H)-f(A)-(DF(A))(H)}{|H|} 
&= \lim_{|H| \to 0} \frac{f(A+H)-f(A)-(DF(A))(H)}{|H|} \\
&= \lim_{|H| \to 0} \frac{|H|^3}{|H|} \\[4pt]
&= \lim_{|H| \to 0} |H|^2 = 0.
\end{align}
$f$ is differentiable at $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $(DF(A))(X)=AXA+XA^2+X^2A+A^2X+AX^2+XAX$.

Is my solution correct ?

Comment: Ask yourself: When $n=1$, so this is all just heavy notation for the real valued function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\; x \mapsto x^3$, does it yield the answer that you expect?

Comment: The derivative is just the part that is linear in $H$.

Comment: No, your solution isn't correct because your $DF(A)$ is not linear in $X$.

Comment: Can someone help me how to approach this problem please ?

Comment: The second comment above already answers your question. $(DF(A))(X)$ is the part of $f(A+X)-f(A)$ that is linear in $X$.